# Where is my mistake...?

Tags: real-numbers

Let
$$x=0.99999\ldots.$$

Clearly $x$ is a rational number.

> I want to find $a,b$ such that 
>   $$x=\frac{a}{b}.$$

Clearly $10x-x=9$ and thus $x=1$. So 
$$1=0.99999\ldots$$

Where is my mistake?

Comment: "Clearly, $x$ is a rational number." Well, it is not so clear if one does not have a clear definition for $0.99\ldots$ and "rational number". :-)

Comment: @RossMillikan: question number 11, asked on the second day that math.se was open.

Comment: What makes you think this is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no mistake. $0{,}\overline{9} =1$ is a true statement.

---

Other proofs of the statement include:

$$\begin{align}0{,}\overline{9} &= 0{,}9 + 0{,}09+0{,}009+\cdots \\&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}9\cdot 10^{-k} \\&=9\cdot \sum_{k=1}^\infty 10^{-k} \\&=9\cdot \frac{1}{10-1} = 1\end{align}$$

or, less strictly, the thought that $\frac19=0{,}11111111\dots$, which means that $1=9\cdot \frac19 = 0{,}99999999\dots$.